# How to get byte data of PDF file from asp.net web method by java-script ajax post?

Tags: javascript, c#, pdf, byte

Consider a file in size of 9.3 MB , it takes 33 MB in the form of byte.Is there any faster techniques to get these byte faster?

[image]

Comment: 9.3 MB take 9.3 MB in bytes. That's why there is the B in MB... ( in other words: please explain what you really mean...)

Comment: byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pdf_file);  I'm using this f'n to read PDF file (9 MB) and it produces the byte array (33 MB).Now,i am trying to get it faster. can u suggest me any alternatives that might result in faster transfer from server to client?

Comment: And how did you measure that this c# `byte[]` takes 33 MB? (Furthermore, you should also edit such fundamental information into your question - there is a [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47467104/edit) link underneath it), otherwise hardly anyone is informed about the change.)

Comment: Do I interpret your screenshot correctly that you measured the size in javascript? And in your comment above you showed how you read the bytes from file in C#? Between those two points in your process much can have happened to the PDF: It can be manipulated (which can make the size increase), it can use a transfer encoding which increases the size, transfer might actually send more than merely the PDF a single time, JavaScript may store the data less than optimally, ... You might want to look into everything that happens on the way.